# Can governments stop information from spreading over the world

Tags: internal-consistency, communication

[Elite Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite_theory) and the book [The Power Elite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_Elite) suggest that the World is really being controlled by groups of elite people who are key persons in dominant institutions (media, military, economic and political) and the ordinary citizen is much powerless subject of manipulation by those entities.

Suppose an organization (with limited power and money) is trying to change this world by creating a document (as video, book, or documentary) to target ordinary people hoping to wake them up and unite everyone. If successful, it will create a massive uprising from all over the world and destroy structure of current power hierarchy.

How can that organization spread the document to everyone before they are stopped by those in power? To oppose those in power they will need to make it fast and get as much people to learn about it as possible. Note: The document will take long to comprehend but truly has the ability to change society.

Can governments and those with relatively unlimited power stop or quarantine this document from spreading out to global scale even go as far as turn down the internet? Of course, they don't want to make a lot of noises and attentions while doing that, it would do more harm than good.

Comment: I suggest to edit this question. The question on information suppression seems to be independent from the elites question. The suppressed information could be a cookie reciepe and the question would be the same. Also, this site is for building **fictional** worlds. The tone of your question makes me wonder if you're asking in a fiction-writing context.

Comment: Are you accounting for the other half of the potential government response: if you can't make it disappear, use your power to cover it up with mounds and mounds of related information so that few actually find the actual document?

Comment: It's already happening all around the world, information can spread really fast on the internet. The real problem is actually of changing the world. I expect that people will be slow to receive the message and it could take years before the first actions are taken.

Answer (score 4):

### Distributed Distribution

The key to allowing a document to spread is to distribute the distribution.  If you only have a single source for the document, it's easy enough to stomp on that source.  If others are disseminating similar versions of the document containing the original message, then it's much harder.

So make something that is easy to transmit and modify the nonessential elements.  An example would be an HTML document with variable CSS.  So it might start with your image as the background, but people could change it to have their own image.  Some might also turn it into a JPEG or similar image format.  This makes the single document turn into multiple documents.  You can't stop just the original.  You have to stomp out all the variants as well.

### Two Parts

Another possibility is to break the message into two parts.  The first part goes out and becomes a mystery.  What does it mean?  It becomes an internet meme, but it doesn't get stomped because the critical people don't recognize it as dangerous.  Then the explanation goes out.  Because the original was popular, the explanation will be as well.  And the explanation will travel much faster given that it just needs to follow the path that the mystery has already broken.

### Hackers

Hack the censored network and allow the message to escape.  This has long precedent in science fiction.  The noble resistance taking over the airwaves to reach the populace.  Perhaps someone pretends to be part of the system until trusted enough to have the access to slip a message into the stream.  Or a small band of armed revolutionaries take over a television station while it's broadcasting globally.  Or a computer hacker remotely bypasses the security to add a message.

### All of the Above

You don't have to choose just one approach.  Use distributed distribution to get the mystery out and then hack the network to get the explanation out.  Or pick two out of three.

Comment: "So it might start with your image as the background, but people could change it to have their own image." lolwhat?  The text would be the same, and therefore would be what an adversary would search/filter for regardless of the bg image.  Maybe a better example would be using synonyms to change content, but I suspect an elite organization would have search capabilities that would trivially pass this obstruction.  I suggest looking at simple techniques that are hard to prevent, not complex  techniques that favor a technically savvy party.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is: no, the government cannot stop the spread of information.

OTOH, the government can certainly cause enough confusion or refuse to act to prevent the information from being accepted or acted upon. In the real world, for example, Hillary Clinton has been caught using a private email server to conduct government business, and highly classified documents have been handled on this machine. In fact, the server was reportedly housed in someone's bathroom in a private house, where minimal to no security was enacted to protect the information being processed.

Now in the real world, of course, this violates so many laws and regulations that Hillary Clinton and the circle of people who surround her and were complicit in this breach of laws and regulations should be in federal prison for the next century or so. But wait; this is not only considered a non issue, but she is considered to be a credible candidate for President of the United States in 2016!

A similar example can be sen on the other side of the world with the Russian invasion of Ukraine. RT and other Russian media services and the so called "Russian Troll Army" are simply filling the airwaves, radio waves, print media and internet with essentially nonsense stories and posts, which distract from and cover the reality of what is happening in Ukraine. This works remarkably well, especially since so many people seem to be primed to believe in conspiracy theories anyway, so many of these stories are taken as truth and run with (even though they may be mutually contradictory).

Finally, if you were to believe in the "power elite" theory, what is to stop either the current power elite simply co-oping the authors of the document(s)? For that matter, suppose the documents created the revolution desired, what is to stop a new power elite from developing in its place?

Comment: That! Govts can't even prevent massive digital piracy of music and movies that costs them millions of dollars in tax every year directly. How could they ever stop a pdf file from being distributed all over the internet through emails, downloads and p2p.

Comment: The political commentary is unnecessary, generally unwelcome on this site, and detracts from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**The revolutionaries will be able to distribute document/video very widely but face a number of significant challenges in getting anyone to take action**

With modern distribution methods such as YouTube, BitTorrent, Tor, eMule, Facebook, and Twitter it would be incredibly difficult for any entity to completely eliminate the document. Note that the US government has been unable to stop distribution of the Edward Snowden documents. If those crown jewels can't be recollected then a video about revolution can't be stopped either.

**Challenges**

*Misinformation Campaigns* - The elite have considerable media controll. Even if they can't suppress the revolutionary video they can drown it in misinformation and doubt. "Fear, Uncertainty and Doubt" have been used by many actors with a vested interest in an economic or political systems staying the way it was. Consider Microsoft's long campaign against Linux as an example of FUD.

*Powerless Poor* - Poor people generally feel powerless and so often do not organize. They frequently lack the skill to effectively organize (if they could organize then they would be the managers and bosses of businesses and *not* poor.)

*Apathy of Middle-class* - The middle class are comfortable as the system that supports the elite also supports them. They have food, shelter and security. They won't act in their own disinterest of revolution posses a risk to their own security. They might think "Yeah, the system sucks but I'm comfortable and somewhat content. A revolution could spoil all that."

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the willingness of the government oppression. Their are plenty of dictatorships to look at that seek to manipulate the truth. Stalin comes foremost to mind. 
They don't have to stop the information if they can change it. Or more likely the government would just release a statement about this "terrorist" agenda. It's all propaganda. The government would be able to reach, influence, manipulate far more people far more quickly.
Also this sounds a lot like 1984  by George Orwell(if you havn't read that do so). 1984 is basically about the government controlling everything including the dissemination of information.

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to @Thucydides answer, I'll say yes, it's easy. In addition to efforts to track down the source of the document, the Power Elite starts distributing corrupted copies, which take various parts of the document and change them to make them obviously wrong - either by being laughable or by being offensive. At the same time, once the originators are located, a campaign to discredit them is launched.

The result is not so much that the message is lost as that it is buried in the noise, and the number of people who believe it never reach critical mass. Eventually the message is forgotten as just another crank, paranoid fantasy.

You know, like "Obama was born in Kenya and his birth certificate was forged" or Bellesisle's "Guns were not widely used in colonial America".